# Inverse Logistic / Sigmoid Function

Tags: math

What is the inverse of the [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (i.e. standard [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)) function?

```
sigmoid(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If

```
y = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

then its inverse is

```
x = ln(y / (1 - y))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `x = -ln((1-y)/y)`?

Comment: @Ethan: they're the same thing since -ln(x)=ln(1/x) .

Comment: Yes, `ln` is the natural logarithm, so `ln(e)=1`.  I think in Java, this is Math.log, though you'll want to verify that since I'm not a Java expert (either check the docs or just checking that `Math.log(e)=1` should be sufficient).

Answer (score 16):

Just to go through the steps:

```
y = 1/(1 + exp(-x))

1 + exp(-x) = 1/y

exp(-x) = 1/y - 1

exp(-x) = 1/y - y/y

exp(-x) = (1 - y)/y

ln(exp(-x)) = ln((1 - y)/y)

-x = ln((1 - y)/y)

x = -ln((1 - y)/y)

x = ln(y/(1 - y))
```

Comment: To omit `inf` or `nan`, add `eps`, e.g. `1e-5` to `y`. Cause `log(0)` does not exist, simply said

Answer (score 1):

The inverse sigmoid may be computed via:

```
inv_sigmoid(x) = ln(x) - ln(1 - x)
```

This is a more numerically stable than the division form `ln(x / (1 - x))`, since the error for subtraction is substantially smaller.

---

Proof:

```
sigmoid(x) = 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

```
inv_sigmoid(x)
  = ln(x) - ln(1 - x)
  = ln(x / (1 - x))
  = -ln((1 - x) / x)
  = -ln(1 / x - 1)
```

Plugging them into each other gives:

```
inv_sigmoid(sigmoid(x))
  = -ln(1 / sigmoid(x) - 1)
  = -ln(1 + exp(-x) - 1)
  = x
```